Template parameter expect error according to P0522 and cppreference but there is none
I know, this title is just a word soup, but I can't formulate my question properly.
What I want to do is this
template<int> struct i {};
template<float> struct f {};
template<float, int> struct fi {};

template<template<auto...> typename> struct catch_all {}; 

// I want to be able to use it like this
catch_all<i>{};
catch_all<f>{};
catch_all<fi>{};

I tried this code with msvc, clang, and gcc and all of them accept it as well as do what I want.
But after checking with cppreference I saw the next example

template<int> struct SI { /* ... */ };
template<template<auto> class> void FA(); // note: C++17
FA<SI>(); // Error


It seems to be taken directly from the P0522. I tried to read both the cppreference and the paper and couldn't understand why this isn't allowed. So I copied this code into the godbolt hoping the compiler error would clear up some things, but all compilers happily accepted this code.
Am I misunderstanding something? Am I doing something wrong? I am hella confused right now.
Edit: I personally use apple clang 15 and c++20 standard, but I tested these code pieces in the latest msvc, clang, and gcc and for each of them tried c++17 and c++20 flags. All of them accepted everything.
Edit2: The problem is that the code compiles while online resources say that it shouldn't. And I personally would like to this code to be valid.

P0522 link: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html

Why should it give error as it should work with C++17 ? Isn't it ? If you change it to C++14 you will see the compiler error.

@SteelFeather both P0522 and cppreference claim FA<SI>(); would be an error. Also in C++17.

@TedLyngmo clarified in the edit

note that you do not need to add "edit" to the question. The question is easier to read without. If someone wants to see the edit history they can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78727661/revisions. In the question we only need the latest version with all the information included (not just as footnotes)

I haven't read the paper but from what I see, I would expect it to compile. Hmm, what am I missing? Ok, read a snippet from the paper. auto should be needed in the SI class template

Too bad the standard doesn't contain such a clear example of when it should fail. C++26 draft page 385 lists a few examples but I guess one would have to actually read the normative text to understand it :-)
